# Apache Spark: dealing with Option/Some/None in RDDs

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark, scala-option

I'm mapping over an HBase table, generating one RDD element per HBase row.  However, sometimes the row has bad data (throwing a NullPointerException in the parsing code), in which case I just want to skip it.

I have my initial mapper return an `Option` to indicate that it returns 0 or 1 elements, then filter for `Some`, then get the contained value:

```
// myRDD is RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)]
val output = myRDD.
  map( tuple => getData(tuple._2) ).
  filter( {case Some(y) => true; case None => false} ).
  map( _.get ).
  // ... more RDD operations with the good data

def getData(r: Result) = {
  val key = r.getRow
  var id = "(unk)"
  var x = -1L

  try {
    id = Bytes.toString(key, 0, 11)
    x = Long.MaxValue - Bytes.toLong(key, 11)
    // ... more code that might throw exceptions

    Some( ( id, ( List(x),
          // more stuff ...
        ) ) )
  } catch {
    case e: NullPointerException => {
      logWarning("Skipping id=" + id + ", x=" + x + "; \n" + e)
      None
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this that's shorter?  I feel like this looks pretty messy, both in `getData()` and in the `map.filter.map` dance I'm doing.

Perhaps a `flatMap` could work (generate 0 or 1 items in a `Seq`), but I don't want it to flatten the tuples I'm creating in the map function, just eliminate empties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change your `getData` to return a `scala.util.Try` then you can simplify your transformations considerably.  Something like this could work:

```
def getData(r: Result) = {
  val key = r.getRow
  var id = "(unk)"
  var x = -1L

  val tr = util.Try{
    id = Bytes.toString(key, 0, 11)
    x = Long.MaxValue - Bytes.toLong(key, 11)
    // ... more code that might throw exceptions

    ( id, ( List(x)
          // more stuff ...
     ) )
  } 

  tr.failed.foreach(e => logWarning("Skipping id=" + id + ", x=" + x + "; \n" + e))
  tr
}
```

Then your transform could start like so:

```
myRDD.
  flatMap(tuple => getData(tuple._2).toOption)
```

If your `Try` is a `Failure` it will be turned into a `None` via `toOption` and then removed as part of the `flatMap` logic.  At that point, your next step in the transform will only be working with the successful cases being whatever the underlying type is that is returned from `getData` without the wrapping (i.e. No `Option`)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative, and often overlooked way, would be using `collect(PartialFunction pf)`, which is meant to 'select' or 'collect' specific elements in the RDD that are defined at the partial function.

The code would look like this:

```
val output = myRDD.collect{case Success(tuple) => tuple }

def getData(r: Result):Try[(String, List[X])] = Try {
        val id = Bytes.toString(key, 0, 11)
        val x = Long.MaxValue - Bytes.toLong(key, 11)
        (id, List(x))
}
```

Comment: This is a good option, however I would be curious to see how this is split. Does this result in a shuffle? Or will it boil down to the same execution plan as my answer?

Comment: @JustinPihony there's no shuffle involved. `collect` can be expressed as: `collection.filter(x=> pf.isDefinedAt(x)).map(pf)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with dropping the data then you can just use `mapPartitions`. Here is a sample:

```
import scala.util._
val mixedData = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,0))
mixedData.mapPartitions(x=>{
  val foo = for(y <- x)
   yield {
    Try(1/y)
  }
  for{goodVals <- foo.partition(_.isSuccess)._1}
   yield goodVals.get
})
```

If you want to see the bad values, then you can use an `accumulator` or just log as you have been.

Your code would look something like this:

```
val output = myRDD.
  mapPartitions( tupleIter => getCleanData(tupleIter) )
  // ... more RDD operations with the good data

def getCleanData(iter: Iter[???]) = {
  val triedData = getDataInTry(iter)
  for{goodVals <- triedData.partition(_.isSuccess)._1}
    yield goodVals.get
}

def getDataInTry(iter: Iter[???]) = {
  for(r <- iter) yield {
    Try{
      val key = r._2.getRow
      var id = "(unk)"
      var x = -1L
      id = Bytes.toString(key, 0, 11)
      x = Long.MaxValue - Bytes.toLong(key, 11)
      // ... more code that might throw exceptions
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what this has to do with partitions - I thought partitions corresponded to the underlying data partitions, in my case HBase regions.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: mapPartitions is the method....meaning that you get the entire partition (in the form of an iterator) to work with instead of one at a time. It is more often used for expensive operations (like opening a connection) that you only want to do once per partition instead of for each element

Comment: Aha, I see - you're taking advantage of the fact that it gives you an iterator, and therefore doesn't expect a one-to-one correspondence between inputs and outputs.