# spark dataframe handle option some none

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, option-type

Similar to [Apache Spark: dealing with Option/Some/None in RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103655/apache-spark-dealing-with-option-some-none-in-rdds) I have a function which is applied via `df.mapPartitions`

```
def mapToTopics(iterator: Iterator[RawRecords]): Iterator[TopicContent] = {
    iterator.map(k => {
      browser.parseString(k.content) >> elementList("doc").map(d => {
        TopicContent((d >> text("docno")).head, (d >> text("text")).head, k.path)
      })
    })
  }
```

The following is also defined:

```
@transient lazy val browser = JsoupBrowser()
case class TopicContent(topic: String, content: String, filepath: String)
case class RawRecords(path: String, content: String)
```

Above will throw an error (`NoSuchElementException`) if no xml tags with text exist (which happens for some malformed documents)
How can I correct and simplify this code to properly handle the options?

When trying to use a util.Try as outlined by the link above and applying a `flatMap` my code would fail, as instead of `Element` it was using `Char`

## edit

```
try {
              Some(TopicContent((d >> text("docno")).head, (d >> text("text")).head, k.path))
            } catch {
              case noelem: NoSuchElementException => {
                println(d.head)
                None
              }
            }
          })
val flattended = results.flatten
```

Will unfortunately only return a `Option[Nothing]`

### edit4

https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/bfb01427b88cf58ea755f912ce539712 a minimal sample without spark (and full code below as well)

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Extract._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.scraper.ContentExtractors.elementList

@transient lazy val browser = JsoupBrowser()
val broken =
  """
    |<docno>
    |   LA051089-0001
    | </docno>
    | <docid>
    |   54901
    | </docid>
    | <date>
    |  <p> May 10, 1989, Wednesday, Home Edition </p>
    | </date>
    | <section>
    |  <p> Metro; Part 2; Page 2; Column 2 </p>
    | </section>
    | <graphic>
    |  <p> Photo, Cloudy and Clear A stormy afternoon provides a clear view of Los Angeles' skyline, with the still-emerging Library Tower rising above its companion buildings. KEN LUBAS / Los Angeles Times </p>
    | </graphic>
    | <type>
    |  <p> Wild Art </p>
    | </type>
  """.stripMargin
val correct =
  """
    |<DOC>
    |<DOCNO> FR940104-0-00001 </DOCNO>
    |<PARENT> FR940104-0-00001 </PARENT>
    |<TEXT>
    |
    |<!-- PJG FTAG 4700 -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG STAG 4700 -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=1 -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG /ITAG -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=4 -->
    |Federal Register
    |<!-- PJG /ITAG -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=1 -->
    |&blank;/&blank;Vol. 59, No. 2&blank;/&blank;Tuesday, January 4, 1994&blank;/&blank;Rules and Regulations
    |
    |<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG /ITAG -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG ITAG l=01 g=1 f=1 -->
    |Vol. 59, No. 2
    |<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG /ITAG -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG ITAG l=02 g=1 f=1 -->
    |Tuesday, January 4, 1994
    |<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG /ITAG -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG /STAG -->
    |
    |<!-- PJG /FTAG -->
    |</TEXT>
    |</DOC>
  """.stripMargin
case class RawRecords(path: String, content: String)

case class TopicContent(topic: String, content: String, filepath: String)
val raw = Seq(RawRecords("first", correct), RawRecords("second", broken))
val result = mapToTopics(raw.iterator)

// Variant 1
def mapToTopics(iterator: Iterator[RawRecords]): Iterator[TopicContent] = {
  iterator.flatMap(k => {
    val documents = browser.parseString(k.content) >> elementList("doc")
    documents.map(d => {
      val docno = d >> text("docno")
      //        try {
      val textContent = d >> text("text")
      TopicContent(docno, textContent, k.path)
      //        } catch {
      //          case _:NoSuchElementException => TopicContent(docno, None, k.path)
      //        }
    }) //.filter(_.content !=None)
  })
}


// When broken down even further you see the following will produce Options of strings
browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc").map(d => {
  val docno = d >> text("docno")
  val textContent = d >> text("text")
  (docno.headOption, textContent.headOption)
})

// while below will now map to characters. What is wrong here?
val documents = browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc")
  documents.map(d => {
  val docno = d >> text("docno")
  val textContent = d >> text("text")
  (docno.headOption, textContent.headOption)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two examples lies in the precedence of the operators. When you're doing `browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc").map(...)`, you're calling `map` on `elementList("doc")`, and not on the whole expression. In order for the first example to behave the same as the second one, you need to write either `(browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc")).map(...)` (recommended) or `browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc") map(...)`.

In the context of scala-scraper, the library you're using, the two expressions mean very different things. With `browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc")` you're extracting a `List[Element]` from a document, and calling `map` on that does just what you'd expect from a collection. On the other hand, `elementList("doc")` is an `HtmlExtractor[List[Element]]` and calling `map` on an extractor creates a new `HtmlExtractor` with the results of the original extractor transformed. That's the reason why you end up with two very different results.

Comment: why is the following `browser.parseString(raw(0).content) >> elementList("doc").map(d => {
  for {
    docno <- d >> text("docno")
    textContent <- d >> text("text")
  } yield (docno.headOption, textContent.headOption)
    
})` binding to the char sequence? I would have expected to iterate over a sequence of elements and flat map the none elements in case of not existing tags. However neither does this solution yield the strings, nor will a flatMap even compile.

Comment: There are a number of issues with that. First of all, you need to add parenthesis around the extraction expression as I explained above; only if you do that will `d` be a single `Element`. Second, `d >> test("docno")` will return a `String` and throw an exception if no element is found - if you want it to return an `Option[String]` you must use the `>?>` operator instead. Finally, you can't `flatMap` with pairs as elements, so you can't yield `(docno.headOption, textContent.headOption)` at the end - with `docno` and `textContent` as strings, you must yield `docno + textContent`.

Comment: I decided to use your suggestion of `>?>` and then filter later on in spark for null values.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the API you are using, but using `headOpton` in a `for` comprehension might help you:

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Extract._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Parse._

iterator.map(k => {
      browser.parseString(k.content) >> elementList("doc").flatMap(d => {
        for {
           docno <- text("docno")).headOption
           text <- (d >> text("text")).headOption
        } yield TopicContent(docno, text, k.path)
      })
})
```

This way you only construct `TopicContent`, really a `Some(TopicContent)`, when *both* `docno` and `text` are present--and `None` otherwise. Then the `flatMap` removes all the `None`s and extracts the content in `Some`s leaving you with a collection of `TopicContent` instances created for all valid XML.

Comment: But flatMap did produce character sequences instead of Strings i.e. Elements thats why one of my approaches earlier failed as well.

Comment: I don't follow. Like I said, I don't know what the API is, but if that code is producing the wrong types it won't even compile. Also, the end result I was going for with `flatMap` is a collection of `TopicContent`s not `String`s. Given all this I don't get what you mean. Earlier you may have been applying `flatMap` over a `String`, which is not what I'm doing here.

Comment: I would also add that the crux of the solution is not the `flatMap`, though it is helpful, but rather the use of `headOption` rather than `head`. As you have found, `head` is unsafe and will cause you problems.

Comment: Again, I don't know this library, but I guess this `HtmlExtractor` isn't a monad and doesn't have `flatMap`. OK, then map over it and then operate on the `List[Element]` inside. At least `List` has a `flatMap`. Or if you don't like `flatMap`, you can use a `filter` and a pattern match to get rid of `None`s. There are a lot of options (no pun intended). Hopefully you now have the tools you need to solve the problem.

Comment: I just looked at the library, and it looks like `doc >> elementList("...")` returns a `List` so I don't know why you can't execute a `flatMap`. The documentation states that you need certain implicit conversions (updated above) in scope, so maybe that's your issue. But anyway, `flatMap` should definitely be available and, in combination with the `headOption`s, solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I still could not get it to work properly. I updated the example above with a minimal sample (without spark and found a strange output as to when Strings or characters are returned.